# Group together rows with similar date in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I have a query that simplifies a table. Here is the query and the result:

**Query**:

```
SELECT 
    test.`ASSEMBLING-TAG`.`Name 5` AS tag,
    DATE(test.`ASSEMBLING-TAG`.datetimetemp) AS date
FROM
    test.`ASSEMBLING-TAG`
GROUP BY `Name 5` , datetimetemp
ORDER BY `Name 5`
```

**Result**:

[image: result]

From this result, I would like to group the rows by tags with the same date and count them, like so:

[image: wanted result]

---

Expected output:

```
| tag            | date       | count |
|----------------|------------|-------|
| G_GoodPieces_R | 2016-01-01 | 10    |
| G_GoodPieces_R | 2016-01-02 | 1     |
```

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Please include your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then simply group by the date of the datetime.

And count them.

```
SELECT 
  t.`Name 5` AS tag,
  DATE(t.datetimetemp) AS date,
  COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM test.`ASSEMBLING-TAG` t
GROUP BY t.`Name 5`, DATE(t.datetimetemp) 
ORDER BY t.`Name 5`
```